# How do i modify .replace to allow numbers, comma and dots

Tags: javascript, regex

I am having a small issue when trying to allow only numbers and comma/dots

I use this to remove numbers from strings

```
.replace(/\D/g,'')
```

How do i modify it so that it allows also comma and dots?

Comment: Please use the search before you ask a new question. I found the duplicate by searching for [`[javascript] replace except number`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+replace+except+number)

Comment: May i ask what the headline was?

Comment: Not sure what you mean...

Comment: Which post ????

Comment: Refresh this page. There is a link to the duplicate above your question.